# conditionally submitting form depending on state of inputs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

Hi All thanks for reading this!

I have created a handle submit function that works on a login form. 
I want the form to not be able to be submit depending on the state of the inputs e.g email,password, password confirm.

Below displays a brief attempt I have had but this does not seem to work correctly.(I know the bottom two are now commented out but they did not work regardless.)

Using this logic what would be the best way to implment it ?

Below is my code in question.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      if (
        !this.state.email < 8 //&&
        //!this.state.password < 8
        // this.state.password !== this.state.passwordConfirm
      ) {
        alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
      } else {

        const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

        fetch("/admin-Add-Users", {
          method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log("Success:", data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
          });
        alert(`Congradulations you have signed up`);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work?". You get an error or it just doesn't work the way you expect it?. Also where and when do you set the state?

Comment: What I meant by it does not work is that it will always prompt please enter the form correctly meaning it is always getting stuck in the if ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I think you can simplify the conditional query.

```
if (!(this.state.email < 8 && this.state.password < 8 && this.state.password == this.state.passwordConfirm)) {
    alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Here we are saying, to be valid, we are checking all props are valid.  Rewritten maybe a little nicer is:

```
checkValidity = ({email, password, passwordConfirm}) => { 
    return email < 8 
            && password < 8 
            && password == passwordConfirm
}


if (!checkValidity(this.state)) {
    alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code as your initial  answer suggested. However it will always throw the alert 'please enter the form correctly' so it doesn't seem to be able to get past the initial if (). This was the problem I was having from the start

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz? Then I can take a look.

Comment: It will need npm Formik but im not sure how I would add the dependence in stack blitz as I tried to install Formik but said it wasn't valid

Answer (score 0):

I was being foolish and the actual logic I had for the if statement was not correct. This fixed it :)

```
if (
      this.state.email.length < 8 ||
      this.state.password.length < 8 ||
      !(this.state.password === this.state.passwordConfirm)
    ) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
      console.log(this.state.email);
      console.log(this.state.password);
    } else {
```